# Enumerate Trust Relationships on a Computer?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory, trust

How do I list which domains are trusted on a Windows computer, in C#?

For instance, if I have a computer whose hostname is `PC01`, and then I joined that computer to an Active Directory domain named `domain.com`, then `PC01` should have trust relationships with both `PC01` (itself) and `domain.com`, so that I could on to `PC01` with user accounts from either one of those "domains."  But I could not log on to `PC01` using a user account from `otherdomain.com`, because there is no trust relationship between `otherdomain.com` and `PC01`.

How do I list what domains I can log on from?

Or at least verify that, if given a domain name, it is or isn't valid to be used to log on to the computer.

I think it might be a little more complex than I first thought.  For instance, I have this code:

```
Forest currentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
Domain currentDomain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
var domainTrusts = currentDomain.GetAllTrustRelationships();
var forestTrusts = currentForest.GetAllTrustRelationships();
```

On my test machine, I am seeing a lot of both forest and domain trusts, but they are not all allowed to log on to my machine.  I think which ones are capable of logging on to my machine must depend on TrustDirection, TrustType, etc...

Comment: have you find answer?